# Crop image with rounded border in CSS

Tags: image, css

Is it possible to use CSS to crop an image so it has a rounded border?

### Original image

[image]

### Cropped image

[image]

How do I do this in CSS?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Introduction to border Radius:

Rounded borders in CSS are achieved through a property called `border-radius` which you can think about like an actual circle or a quarter of a circle for each corner that has some radius and crops the selected element sharp edges to match the quarter circle curve. This is what happens when you use it with pixel values or fixed values if used with `%` values such as `border-radius: 50%;` it's totally a different story.

here is a good resource to learn more about `border-radius` [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)
or [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius)

### The solution:

The thing you want to achieve can be done like this:

**CSS:**

```
img.foo {    
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="foo" src="./foo.jpg" />
```

See [border-radius.com](https://border-radius.com/) for a generator.

Comment: Well, I've upvoted but just make sure it's `img.foo` and not `img .foo` your selector is incorrect, there shouldn't be any space between the `img` and `.foo`

Answer (score 2):

Add a border radius `border-radius:4px;`

Answer (score 1):

That crop image in css, use it as a `background.

Html:

```
<div class="cropped-image"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.cropped-image {
   width: 100px; // crop by width
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   border-radius: 10px;
   background: url("your image url") no-repeat center; // show image center
}
```

OR use `clip` - http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clip

```
img{
   clip: rect(0px, 50px, 50px, 0px);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense at all. Why would you restrict the width to 100px? That's not what the OP asked. There's also no need to make it a background, as `border-radius` is just as readily applied to `img` elements. And there's no such thing as `-msie-border-radius`.

Comment: Unfortunately, [clip is now deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip).

Answer (score 0):

**Used to this**

```
-webkit-border-radius:4px;
-moz-border-radius:4px;
-o-border-radius:4px;
border-radius:4px;
```

Comment: There never was an `-o-border-radius`. Don't just go appending those prefixes to every property you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

By crop, if you want to make it like the image you have i.e https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrsLN.png, you can do it in two ways.

1. Add a border-radius by CSS
2. Crop that image to that borders roundness in your image editing software and save it as gif or png for transparency.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579353977828-2a4eab540b9a">
<style>
img{
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>
```

You Can Use `width` to specify the width of the image;
And, Use `border-radius` to specify the border radius (corner's radius) of the Image...